# Select data from variable_tableName in Sqlite

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I am using Fmdb wrapper around Sqlite, everything is working fine.
Now I want to load data from a variable table, the table name is stored in an NSString. I don't know how to write query for that. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used `FMDB Wrapper`. But reading the [Documetation](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), it looks like `-executeQuery` is a method from `FMDatabase` Class that takes the `QueryString` as a parameter and returns an object of `FMResultSet` Class. So, argument is of `NSString` type and you can use `%@` operator to add the dynamic string values in your `QueryString`.

**Sample Code :**

```
FMResultSet *results = nil;
results = [yourDB executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@",variable_tableName]];
```

Comment: can you please help me regarding the same issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095519/fmdb-select-query-with-variable-table-name